# Cesàro's Theorem application: what is wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Consider this well known result:

${\bf Theorem:}$ Let $(a_n)_n\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence and let

$$b_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k.$$

Thus we have

$$a_n\to l\implies b_n \to l,$$
(but, in general, the converse does not hold).

Starting from this result, I would like to show that if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are as above, it holds
$$\liminf_{n\to +\infty} a_n\leq\liminf_{n\to +\infty} b_n\leq\limsup_{n\to +\infty} b_n\leq\limsup_{n\to +\infty} a_n.$$

I tried in this way:

$l$ belongs to the adherence values of $a_n$, thus $a_{n_k}$ exists such that $a_{n_k}\to l$ which implies, by using the previous theorem, that $b_{n_k}\to l$, and then $l$ belongs to the adherence values of $b_n$ too. Thus the set of adherence values of $a_n$ is $\subset$ in the set of adherence values of $b_n$, and since $\limsup$ is the maximum value of adherence values and $\liminf$ is the minimum value of adherence values, it is

$$\limsup_{n\to +\infty} a_n\leq \limsup_{n\to +\infty} b_n,$$

which is exactly the converse of what I wanted to prove. Could anyone please help me to understand if I am missing something?

Also an alternative idea is well accepted. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Take a look at the [General Form of Stolz Cesaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#The_general_form).

Comment: @TitoEliatron I think it does not help in this case.

Comment: Why not? is exactly what you're trying to prove, with $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n$ and $b_n=n$

Comment: It works with diverging sequences, isn't it?

Comment: Only unboundedness and monotonicity of $(b_n)_n$ is required.

Comment: In the notation of the Theorem in your link, I have to prove, in order to answer my question, that $\liminf_{n\to +\infty} \frac{A_n}{b_n}\leq\limsup_{n\to +\infty} a_n$, which is not shown in the link

Comment: If you take $A_n = \sum_{k=1}^n$ and $B_n=n$ everything works.